# What is a trick in asprintf() to release the memory?

Tags: c

Below is a snippet cited from "21 century C".
I can't figure out why the outcome of the program is so different if I release the memory with free(tmp_string_for_extend), not free(write_to) in the macro Sasprintf. Thanks,

```
#define Sasprintf(write_to,  ...) {           \
    char *tmp_string_for_extend = (write_to); \
    asprintf(&(write_to), __VA_ARGS__);       \
    free(tmp_string_for_extend);              \
}

int main() {
    inti = 3;
    char *q = NULL;
    Sasprintf(q,"select * from tab");
    Sasprintf(q,"%s where col%i is not null",q,i);
    printf("%s\n",q);
}
```

Comment: Assume for a second we didn't all read "21 Century C", you need to specify what outcome you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: `asprintf()` is not defined by the C Standard or POSIX. I'd try to **not use** that function.

Comment: @StoryTeller I thnk the question is well-formed.  The code sure appears to be utter garbage, emanating from the south end of a northbound bull.  At **best** it relies upon an ability to access freed memory safely and is thus undefined behavior. At worst it's completely wrong.  Burn the book.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Well formed? Is it BS from the book or from the OP's own feverish mind? Did the book do something different? Hardly well-formed.

Comment: The question is self-contained and clear:  "This code is confusing.  I can't figure it out."  I've been coding in C for decades, and it makes my head hurt too.

Comment: @StoryTeller This appears to be the code in question:  https://github.com/sandersch/21st-century-c/blob/master/text/sasprintf.c

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Okay, it's BS from the book. It's still up to the OP to make a point of saying as much.

Comment: `free(tmp_string_for_extend);` does not update `write_to`, yet frees memory associated with it.  `Sasprintf()` macro is poor code.

Comment: @chux  I don't get it, could you explain why free(tmp_string_for_extend) does not update write_to to free the memory associated with it? Thanks,

Comment: @codexplorer After `free(tmp_string_for_extend)` is called the data pointed to by `write_to` is freed. This is `q` in `Sasprintf(q,"select * from tab");`.  Now `Sasprintf(q,"%s where col%i is not null",q,i);` is called with the invalid pointer.  This is "OK" as `q` is `NULL`, but had code been `char *q = malloc(10);` the free due to `Sasprintf(q,"select * from tab");` would be passing a non-NULL (and now invalid pointer) to `Sasprintf(q,"%s where col%i is not null",q,i);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at these two lines:

```
char *q=NULL;
Sasprintf(q,"select * from tab");
```

If we expand the macro it will become (roughly):

```
char *q=NULL;
{
    char *tmp_string_for_extend = (q);
    asprintf(&(q), "select * from tab");
    free(tmp_string_for_extend);
}
```

It should be quite clear that the initialization of `tmp_string_for_extend` will be equivalent to initialize it to `NULL`, since `q` at that point is `NULL`.

So when you call `free(tmp_string_for_extend)` you're effectively doing `free(NULL)`. Calling `free` with a null pointer does *nothing*.

If you instead do `free((write_to))` in the macro then it will be expanded to `free((q))` which will free the memory you just allocated with `asprintf`. Dereferencing `q` after that (which happens when you print the contents) will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should call `free(q)` *after* you're fully done with `q`.

---

Also note that for most `sprintf` variants, probably including the GNU libc-specific `asprintf` function, using the same argument for both source (as an argument) and as destination usually is *undefined behavior* as well. Which makes your second macro invocation invalid. And even if it was defined, then it could be a memory leak if `asprintf` doesn't free any non-null pointer.

Comment: Summary:  This code is a horrible an failed attempt to skip having to call `free()` after using `asprintf()`.

Comment: Isn't the point of the `free(tmp_string_for_extend)` to free the memory allocated on the _previous_ invocation of the macro? Then there is a memory leak in that the final invocation never frees its memory.

Comment: @DavidBowling I'd opine that it's a bit of a stretch to infer any intent behind that code.  If that is the intent, the example usage relies on being able to access the created string after it's been freed.  It looks more like the code "works" only by accident.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Is there a difference between free((write_to)) and free(write_to)?

Comment: @codexplorer No. Except that for macro arguments *always* use extra parentheses to prevent some otherwise hard to find problems.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I agree with you that I should call free(q) after I'm fully done with q. Originally the author uses asprintf to append the strings, but in order to prevent a memory leak from the snippet at the original address of q which isn’t released when q is given a new location by asprintf, the author uses macro Sasprintf(i.e. safer asprintf) in place of asprintf. But in my case if it really wants to release the original memory, it has to use free(write_to), not free(tmp_string_for_extend) and eventually the macro doesn't really take effect to release the memory it was allocated.